# Is code cleanliness a good enough reason to use a property over a field?

Tags: c#, .net, properties, coding-style

I have a class that is Enumerated to allow subscripting of a list contained within it. For this reason, the List does not need to be publicly accessible through a field or property.

```
public class Foo : IEnumerable<Bar>
{
    private List<Bar> _positions;
```

If I have other properties in my class with private setters, future programmers will see `PascalCase`, `PascalCase`, `PascalCase`, `_asdfghjk`. Huh? What the hell was that? `_asdfghjk` sure does look pretty ugly.

Is the consistency created by making `_positions` into something like

```
private List<Bar> Positions { get; set; }
```

a good enough reason for using a property over a field?

Comment: Why have the underscore at all? Just use `positions`.

Comment: Code cleanliness sounds like a good reason to change the name, not necessarily the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as you are *consistent* then somebody reading your code will not be surprised.

If the convention that you are using is `_privateField` then so long as you're using it everywhere a person reading your code will get used to it.

The danger comes if you mix styles.

To be honest, personally I'd be confused to find a private auto-getter/setter properties in a class; to quote MSDN:

> Properties enable a class to expose a **public** way of getting and setting values, while hiding implementation or verification code.
>   <sub>--[Properties (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx)</sub>

and

> Generally, you should use fields only for variables that have **private** or **protected** accessibility.
>   <sub>--[Fields (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx)</sub>

Finally, if you are using [StyleCop](https://stylecop.codeplex.com/), then if you start a field with an underscore, then it will warn:

> Field names must not start with an underscore. [StyleCop Rule: SA1309]

Comment: `...if you are using StyleCop, then if you start a field with an underscore, then it will warn`
Thats only a convention and can vary from team to team. It is just the default StyleCop configuration

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't introduce a fully-private property just for the sake of it. It can be useful to do so if it computes the property value from state, or performs validation etc - but don't just do it for the sake of it.

Personally I'd just call it `positions` instead of `_positions` - heck, you could call it `Positions` if you really wanted all the names to be consistent with each other (but inconsistent with normal naming conventions).

It shouldn't be a particularly rare thing to have a field which *isn't* exposed by a property - I'd be worried if seeing such a thing bothered a developer. Likewise not every property ought to be an automatically-implemented property, so developers should be used to seeing both `foo` and `Foo` as members of a class (with `foo` being private).